# In App purchase not working for iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, in-app

I have running application and it's working fine for iOS8.3 and prior but not working for iOS 8.4.

Actually when i call for product list i am not getting any response or product detail like before.

If any one facing same issue and have any solutions then please help me. It not working for my iPhone with iOS 8.4 but working with iOS 8.3 and prior fine.

Comment: Do you talk about an app download from app store or installed in developer environment?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this issue today as well. However yesterday it was working just fine on iOS 8.4 - so I think the issue could be on Apple's end. I have tried with 2 devices and the simulator. Unfortunately I do not have a solution either.

Comment: This is now working for me again. Must have been an issue with Apple.